# Can a continuous surjection between compacts behave bad wrt Borel probability?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Suppose A,B are compact metric spaces with Borel probability measures $m_A$ and $m_B$ correspondingly. Let $f:A\to B$ be a continuous surjection. Is it true that if $m_A(K) = 1$ for a Borel set $K$ then $m_B(f(K) ) = 1$ ?
The fact that $f(K)$ is Borel is discussed in [Continuous images of open sets are Borel?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159840/continuous-images-of-open-sets-are-borel)

UPD:
Suppose additionally that $A$ is second-countable (for the link I have attached to work).

I asked continuations of this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1178009/can-a-continuous-surjection-between-compacts-behave-bad-wrt-borel-fully-supporte) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1178056/can-a-continuous-surjection-from-a-hilbert-cube-to-a-segment-behave-bad-wrt-lebe).

Comment: I don't see how the question you linked implies that $f(K)$ is Borel.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I have to suppose additionally that A is second countable. The question is still interesting for me under this assumption.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $A = B = \{1,2\}$ with the discrete topologies and $m_A, m_B$ the unique probability measures with $m_A (\{1\})=1$ and $m_B(\{2\})=1$ and $f(1)=1$, $f(2)=2$.

This yields a counterexample by taking $K=\{1\}$.

Comment: Thank you, this solves my original question. Is it possible to construct a counterexample in the case if $m_A$ and $m_B$ are fully supported? 

Or I should better ask it as a separate question?

Comment: @demitau separate question