# Can a continuous surjection between compacts behave bad wrt Borel fully supported probability?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Suppose A,B are compact metric spaces with fully supported Borel probability measures $m_A$ and $m_B$ correspondingly. Suppose that $A$ is second-countable.
Let $f:A\to B$ be a continuous surjection.

1. Is it true that if $m_A(K) = 1$ for a Borel set $K$ then
   $m_B(f(K) ) = 1$ ?
2. If the answer to the first question is no, would
       it help if I assume in addition that $f$ is Holder continuous
       (with respect to metrics that are compatible with Borel structures)?

This is a continuation of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1177078/can-a-continuous-surjection-between-compacts-behave-bad-wrt-borel-probability).

The original motivation for the question is the case when $A$ is a Hilbert cube and $B$ is a line segment.

UPD: I have asked a continuation of this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1178056/can-a-continuous-surjection-from-a-hilbert-cube-to-a-segment-behave-bad-wrt-lebe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is still not true. Let $A = B = [0,1]$ and let $(q_n)_n$ be an enumeration of $\Bbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$ and $(p_n)_n$ an enumeration of $(\Bbb{Q} + \sqrt{2}) \cap [0,1]$.

Define

$$
m_A (M) = \sum_{n \in \Bbb{N} : q_n \in M} \frac{1}{2^n}
$$

and

$$
m_B (M) = \sum_{n \in \Bbb{N} : p_n \in M} \frac{1}{2^n}.
$$

Since $\Bbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$ is contained in ${\rm supp} m_A$, we see that $m_A$ has full support. Likewise, $m_B$ has full support.

But if we let $f$ be the identity map (which is certainly Hölder continuous) and $K = \Bbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$, then $m_B (f(K)) = 0$, since $\Bbb{Q}$ and $\Bbb{Q} + \sqrt{2}$ are disjoint.