# Can a continuous surjection from a Hilbert cube to a segment behave bad wrt Lebesgue measures?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Suppose $\hat{I}$ is a Hilbert cube and $I$ is a line segment. 
Consider Lebesgue measures $m_1$ and $m_2$ on $\hat{I}$ and $I$ correspondingly. 
Let $f:\hat{I}\to I$ be a continuous surjection.

1. Is it true that if $m_1(K) = 1$ for a Borel set $K$ then
   $m_2(f(K) ) = 1$ ?
2. If the answer to the first question is no, would
       it help if I assume in addition that $f$ is Hölder continuous
       (with respect to metrics that are compatible with Borel structures)?

This is a continuation of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1177078/can-a-continuous-surjection-between-compacts-behave-bad-wrt-borel-probability).

P.S. This is the third question in the series, I promise this one is the last.

Comment: What exactly do  you mean by "Lebesgue measure" on the Hilbert cube?

Comment: Just the product of the Lebesgue measures on the segments which are taken to get the product.  Or its homeomorphis image like here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75932/measure-on-hilbert-space/269369#269369

Comment: Ok. I will have to think about that. For part 2: I don't think that assuming Hölder continuity will help. Because if $f$ is continuous, we can just take the new metric $d'(x,y) := d_A(x,y) + d_B (f(x), f(y))$ on $A$ and $f$ will even be Lipschitz with respect to this metric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer from [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/199521/can-a-continuous-surjection-from-a-hilbert-cube-to-a-segment-behave-bad-wrt-lebe/199525#199525). A counterexample can be constructed using  [The Devil's staircase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function). If one replaces $\hat{I}$ by $I$, than the Cantor function is Holder continuous surjection and it is easy to construct a full measure set K (the set where the function is locally constant = the union of middle third intervals = the set of numbers whose base 3 expansion contains at least one 1) that is mapped to a zero measure set (the set of numbers with base 2 expansion having only finite nonzero coordinates).

To understand that $K$ has measure $1$ look at $I\setminus K$. It is a set of numbers without a single $1$ in base-3 expansion. I will show that this set has measure zero due to standard ergodic theory.  Base $3$ expansion of a number $y$ can be contructed by assigning a sequence of digits $\{\sigma_k\}$ from $\{0,1,2\}^\mathbb{N}$ to the trajectory of $y$ under the action of $E_3 (x) = 3x (\mod 1)$. 
If $E_3^{k} (x) < 1/3$, put $\sigma_k = 0$, if  $1/3 < E_3^{k} (x) < 2/3$, put $\sigma_k = 1$, and so on.

As $E_k$ is ergodic with respect to Lebesgue measure for every $k\geq 2$, for Lebesgue almost every $x$ the trajectory of $x$ under the action of $x \to 3x  (\mod 1)$ visits every open set (including middle third).

To understand that $f(K)$ has zero measure one can use a similar argument -- for Lebesgue almost every $x$ the trajectory of $x$ under the action of $x \to 2x  (\mod 1)$ visits every open set (including second half) infinitely many times.

To handle the case of Hilbert cube one can take a composition of the Cantor function and a projection.

In fact, there are other similar examples [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_function)

Comment: Can you at least link to the Math Overflow post? Adding an outline of the construction would be even better than a pure link.